# Please help flicker implement on android

Tags: android

Anybody idea how to integrate flicker to my application on android?. i got API key secrete key for my application from flicker.com site. i am confused how to use it. Api key separate for every user? how to get token number for flickr by code ? i have refer photostream and Flicker free code . but both code give the exceptiion.?

plz any body have code ,plz give me it?

also explain steps for implement it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.howto.web.html) howto, it'll tell you everything you need to know about getting your key and configuring it. Once you have your key and your secret, all you need to do in order to use get a flickr photo-handle is this:

```
private void setUpFlickr()
{   
  try 
  {
    Flickr flickr = new Flickr(flickrApiKey, flickrSecret, new REST());
    flickrConnection = flickr.getPhotosInterface();
  }
  catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
  { 
    e.printStackTrace(); //Proper error handling goes here
  } 
}
```